# boot animation loop on nexus 4

Tags: rooting, nexus-4

I realise this is a common problem and have read many solutions, but many seem to not work in my case. I got into this situation after flashing cwm (in order to later root the device).

I can get into cwm easily and wipe cache/dalvik and factory-reset easily (and have done so a few times). I do get the following mounting errors when doing the factory reset (i copied only the error lines):

```
Error mounting /data!
skipping format...
formatting /sdcard/.android_secure
E:unknown volume "/sdcard/.android_secure"
```

One lead that I currently have for the problem is that I'm not sure whether usb debugging was enabled.

On Skipsoft Android toolkit for example I'm stuck on "waiting for adb mode".

Comment: Could you try a different version of CWM or a totally different recovery?

Comment: And could you please elaborate how title and tags correspond with your question text? What is your problem: a) you want to root (tag), b) you've got a boot-loop (title), c) you've got trouble with your CWM (text)? Please [edit] your question and clearify.

Comment: sry for being unclear. anyhow, wugfresh solved the problem.

Comment: @falafa you can help me. I am stuck with my nexus 4 boot loop problem. Please help me how can i slove my phone with wugfresh tool?